# Extending the Laravel Http Facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-facade

I'm trying to find the right way to extend the Laravel Http Client Facade. I don't want to do this every time when I want to get something from the response of my request. I would like to add some more helpers to prevent this. Also I can't directly extend the client, because I'm using the facade with a macro to ease my life.

```
    json_decode($this->getBody()->getContents())->id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already [built into the client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#making-requests).

```
$response = Http::get('http://example.com/users/1');
$response->json()['id'];
$response->object()->id;
```

Or even:

```
Http::get('http://example.com/users/1')['id'];
```

Comment: Thank you, you are a BOSS, I will accept the answer in 10 minutes!